# How do you change the date format when modifying an event in Calendar?

Tags: calendar, internationalization, timezone

I would to change the date format when modifying an event in Calendar. Currently, Calendar shows the date as 12/10/2020 when I go to modify the date/time. This is the same as is displayed above the calendar preview in System Preferences → Date & Time.

My formats in System Preferences → Language & Region → Advanced... → Dates are the following:

```
Short  : 2020-06-01 
Medium : 01 Jun 2020
Long   : 01 June 2020
Full   : Monday, 1 June 2020
```

[image]

Calendar seems to be using the Medium format when creating a new Event. In Calendar, if I right click → New Event, the date is displayed as `10 Dec 2020 13:00 to 14:00`.

[image]

However, when I click on that line to modify the date/time, the window changes to

```
starts  : 12/10/2020 13:00
ends    : 12/10/2020 14:00
```

[image]

Where is Calendar getting the format of month/day/year from? In Calendar → Preferences, I could not find a way to change this, as the only preferences there are things like the Days per week, Start week on, and how many hours to display at once.

I am on macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

Comment: I'd have thought that would be in Language & Region prefs - you're set to US presumably, so you get US date formats MMDDYYYY rather then European DDMMYYYY

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah, changing the Region to different places in Europe changes that specific setting (UK: 10/12/2020, Germany: 10.12.2020), but it also changes the primary language and a bunch of other settings. I'd like to change just that calendar format to be closer to ISO 8601, but I don't know if it is possible. Modifying the Medium date format will change what the calendar shows in the event when you aren't editing it, so I thought it would make sense that you can also customize the date format when you are editing it.

Comment: This 'feature' is present in Big Sur as well and not limited to Calendar. Similar behavior can be observed in Reminders.

Comment: You ought to be able to change it to UK, then swap currencies back to dollars, temperatures back to ℉ etc.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think that might have to be my solution. Switching my region to UK changes that specific calendar format, and then I had to reset the primary language, temperature, currency, and measurement units. I haven't yet noticed any other changes besides the date format.